# Spring JPA Multiple join conditions

Tags: java, spring, database, jpa, entity

I am working on my first Spring Boot application and I am having a bit of a struggle within the joining of two tables/entities.

I need to join my user_roles table to the users table so that the user will get its correct roles directly from the database (postgres).
The thing that is my the fact that the roles are depending on the current organization that the user is in. The app allows a user to work for multiple companies at once, and switch between them. The roles a user has in organization 1 may not apply to organization 2.

The user has a roles field in the database which should be mapped to the correct roles. The user also has a 'current_organization_id' field, which contains the current user organization.

I think the solution wouldn't be that difficult but my brain is not solving this case yet.

Roles could be mapped on 'user_id' (UUID) and 'cur_org_id' (UUID) with an table like 'user_role_within_org'. But I don't know how to do that within JPA.

An explanation how your solution is solving this would be nice, it is important to understand code and not just copy paste it ;)

Thanks in advance,
Jesse

###### Current database model

[image: Current database model]

Comment: Can you please post your database model?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli added a screenshot of the database model to the post ;)

Comment: I can't find user_role_within_org

Comment: Is this database pre-existing ?

Comment: This is the database as it currently stands. It needs some changes to work for the case that I want. That also explains why there is no user_role_within_org table yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try storing a `Map` of Organization->List in the `User`.

```
@Entity
class User {
    @ManyToMany
    Map<Organization, List<Role>> roles;
}
```

To get the roles in current organization try the following JPQL:

```
SELECT VALUE(r) 
FROM User u JOIN u.roles r
WHERE KEY(r).id = u.currentOrganization.id
```

Comment: It doesn't look like the Map type can be stored to the database. At least that's what intellij tells me.

Comment: Still gives me the same message: 'Many To Many' attribute value type should not be 'Collection'

I have the following in the code.

```@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Map<AppOrganization, Collection<AppRole>> roles;```